# Auto-rotate certificate for the Service principal key while creating Express V2(MS Internal) service connection

Tags: autorotate, service-principal

Question: Is there any way we can create an auto-rotate certificate for the Service principal key while creating Express V2(MS Internal) service connection?

My team owns a web application and we deploy our service using the EV2 pipeline. For the deployment, we use a secret when authenticating but looks like it cant be auto-rotated. We tried creating a certificate as well, but since we have to update pfx certificate on the portal it's not auto rotatable.